# Jquery Mobile: New Ajax Loaded Page not Loading new JS

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is my current setup.

I have two pages running on the jquery mobile framework.

- index.php
- article.php

In bother headers I have a js file called ratings.

here is my js `ratings.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rating_1").click(function () {
        $("#rating_2").css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px');
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-45px 0px');
    }); 
});
```

When I load `index.php` and then go to `article.php` none of my triggers to `ratings.js` work.

If I add `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` my triggers work. 
However then I lose the ability to have my loader wheel come up.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Important: Use `$(document).bind('pageinit')`, not
>   `$(document).ready()`
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   `$(document).ready()` function so everything will execute as soon as
>   the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Try:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $("#rating_1").click(function() {
        $("#rating_2").css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px');
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-45px 0px');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put everything inside:

```
<div id="page" data-role="page">
<!--here-->
</div>
```

Script in the `<head></head>` section will not be loaded while ajax loading.

Comment: I should put the js from ratings.js in there?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that jQuery loads pages via Ajax and therefore, it only loads the

```
<div data-role="page"> </div>
```

parts of the page.

You can do 3 things to solve this kind of an issue.

1.) The one which you have already tried ( which is to make a data-ajax=false ) which makes your page load completely again and not showing your loader wheel.

2.) You can make the event a live event:

```
$("#rating_1").live('click', function () {
$("#rating_2").css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px');
$(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-45px 0px');
});
```

This will make it look for any new #rating_1 and will add the click event to it.'

3.) Instead of using `$(document).ready` you can use `$( '#myPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){};` function.